# how to convert google slides to pdf with notes using Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Trying to convert google (ppt) slides into pdf with slide notes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding the code you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820025/4243927) can serve as a guide for you.

Overall what you are trying to achieve can be done with Apps Script, so you should start experimenting with it. If you are new to Google Apps Script then I recommend you start with a [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/fundamentals-codelabs) to get the fundamentals, and then move on to [Extending Slides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides#get_started).