# Save one Google Slide as pdf with Google Apps Script while preserving the format

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

The solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819079/save-google-slide-as-pdf-using-google-apps-script) is correct but in my experience, a slide in 4:3 format will be saved as a pdf in the 16:9 format, which scrambles the contents.

How can I save a Google Slide to pdf and make the output pdf preserve the original slide format?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Solution:**

```js
function SaveAsPDF() {
  var googleSlidesId = "#############################" //replace with presentation id
  var slidesBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/"+googleSlidesId+"/export?format=pdf").getBlob();
  var pdf = DriveApp.createFile(slidesBlob);
  Logger.log(pdf.getUrl());
}
```

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: This does not preserve the file format. A slide formatted in 4:3 will turn into a pdf in 16:9 format.

Comment: Solution is working fine. please test it again. [4:3 slides file](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1h8sl8T0AGjFQ-sv9LAExh1BdM-MWj2Uk3mD6-PSgy6k/edit#slide=id.gcb9a0b074_1_0) and [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Iei3vsqWtAr3-j_MecDRZ1ggWEnEl2d/view)

Comment: Sorry I didn't test your solution ‍♂️. Will do.

Comment: I tested the solution and it still outputs files in 16:9 format. Strange.

Comment: Got it. I had introduced additional steps which turned the Slide Presentation in 16:9 format, so of course the pdf was 16:9 as well. Your solution is perfectly fine. If you edit it I'll be able to remove the downvote.